# How to run a thread inside an object using pthread

Tags: c++, pthreads, raspberry-pi, cross-compiling, raspbian

I'm having some trouble using this code.

```
void BV4618::InitializeThreads(void){
    pthread_t T_FIFO, T_Buffer;
    pthread_create( &T_FIFO, NULL, FIFO, NULL);
    pthread_create( &T_Buffer, NULL, readKBuffer, NULL);
}
```

The methods FIFO and readKBuffer do these things..

```
void *BV4618::FIFO(void*){
    while (isWorking){
        if (qsize > 0){
            if(params[0] == -1){
                ReceiveData();
            }else{
                SendData(params[0]);
            }
            //printf("Processing in position %d value %d\n", qsize, params[0]);
            ShifterQ();
        }else{
            usleep(50000);
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

The point is, in a procedural way everything has worked fine without problem. Now, that i'm gonna rewriting everything using classes, i'm encountering some problems like

```
cannot convert 'BV4618::FIFO' from type 'void* (BV4618::)(void*)' to type 'void* (*)(void*)'    BV4618.cpp
```

The constructor calls a method named "InitializeThreads" that launches the threads which continuosly are listening for something on that kind of object. What's the solution for the above problem?

Comment: C-style APIs don't go together well with object-oriented C++ code. The `C++11` `std::thread` does rather well.

Comment: I'm working with a custom toolchain for Cross-Compiling. 

I got this error:


This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options. DomoHome2  line 32, external location: /Volumes/rpi-crosscompiler-toolchain/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/c++0x_warning.h C/C++ Problem

I'm on OSX 10.9.3

Comment: @pmr, his problem has nothing to do with mixing C and C++. Before C++11, there was plain C++ for years and somehow programmers managed to use threads from different libraries such as the pthread library.

Comment: @AlexisWilke His specific problem is: "How to pass a member function pointer to a message expecting a function pointer?" This is a classic problem of interfacing C APIs and C++ objects. Sure, people dealt with this for years, but it is painful and ugly and the reason why C libraries are usually wrapped.

Comment: If it's more reliable I can use thread library.. But i'm having some trouble with the Cross GCC compiler who is keeping telling me that thread could not be resolved. Guess that is a common issue on C++11 isn't it? I'm on mac osx and eclipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a pthread expert, but the problem is that you try to give a pointer to a member function when the definition of pthread_create() is expecting a function:

```
int pthread_create(pthread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t *attr,
                    void *(*start_routine) (void *), void *arg);
```

pthread will then call a normal **"standalone" function** giving it arg as argument.

A **member function** however does not work like a "standalone" function.  It is meaningless without without its class and the data that goes along with it.

I'd recommend to create a static wrapper function, and use `this` (pointer to the class) as argument.  The wrapped would then recast the argument as being a BV4618 and call invoque the member function of the class.

The wrapper is a **static member function**.  Static member means that it's independent of the class data:

```
static void* BV4618::my_wrapper (void* arg) {
    ((BV4618*)arg)->FIFO( );
}
```

*Please note, that in real life, when using separate class declaration (in a header) and definition (code implementation), the **static** keywork must be provided in the declaration only*.

For this to work, you need to redfine slightly your FIFO function, as it will no longer expect an argument:

```
void *BV4618::FIFO(){
    ...
}
```

Your init code would then look like:

```
...
pthread_create( &T_FIFO, NULL, my_wrapper, this);
...
```

Comment: Thank you, but now i'm having another problem.

    cannot declare member function 'static void*     BV4618::wrapperBeep(void*)' to have static linkage [-fpermissive]

which is the same error for the three static methods..

Comment: Ok !  I think it's a minor issue. Put the keywork "static" in the header within the class declaration.  Don't put it in the code body where you define your function (the compiler will know that it's static from the declaration).  In my sample above, for my test compiles, I didn't make the effort to separate definition and declaration ;-)